# The subtract calculation goes wrong in c#

Tags: c#, .net, subtraction

I am writing a program with c#. I've written logic for subtraction of three numbers but it shows the wrong output. Below my code. Any help will be appreciated.

```
private void btnSub_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ch != "-")
        {
            num1 =  num1 - double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        }
        else
        {
            num1= Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
            ch = "";
        }

        textBox1.Text = "";

        op = "-";

        textBox1.Text += op;

    }
```

My complete code:

```
namespace Cal1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        static double num1, num2 = 0;
        string op;
        static string ch = "";


        private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text == "+" || textBox1.Text == "-" || textBox1.Text == "*" || textBox1.Text == "/")
            {
                textBox1.Text = "";

                textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + button1.Text;
            }
            else
            {
                textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + button1.Text;
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text == "+" || textBox1.Text == "-" || textBox1.Text == "*" || textBox1.Text == "/")
            {
                textBox1.Text = "";

                textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + button2.Text;
            }
            else
            {
                textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + button2.Text;
            }
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text == "+" || textBox1.Text == "-" || textBox1.Text == "*" || textBox1.Text == "/")
            {
                textBox1.Clear();
                textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + button3.Text;
            }
            else
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + button3.Text;
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text == "+" || textBox1.Text == "-" || textBox1.Text == "*" || textBox1.Text == "/")
            {
                textBox1.Clear();
                textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + button4.Text;
            }
            else
                textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + button4.Text;
        }

        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text == "+" || textBox1.Text == "-" || textBox1.Text == "*" || textBox1.Text == "/")
            {
                textBox1.Clear();
                textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + button5.Text;
            }
            else
                textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + button5.Text;
        }

        private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text == "+" || textBox1.Text == "-" || textBox1.Text == "*" || textBox1.Text == "/")
            {
                textBox1.Clear();
                textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + button6.Text;
            }
            else
                textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + button6.Text;
        }

        private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text == "+" || textBox1.Text == "-" || textBox1.Text == "*" || textBox1.Text == "/")
            {
                textBox1.Clear();
                textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + button7.Text;
            }
            else
                textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + button7.Text;
        }

        private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text == "+" || textBox1.Text == "-" || textBox1.Text == "*" || textBox1.Text == "/")
            {
                textBox1.Clear();
                textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + button8.Text;
            }
            else
                textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + button8.Text;
        }

        private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text == "+" || textBox1.Text == "-" || textBox1.Text == "*" || textBox1.Text == "/")
            {
                textBox1.Clear();
                textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + button9.Text;
            }
            else
                textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + button9.Text;
        }

        private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text == "+" || textBox1.Text == "-" || textBox1.Text == "*" || textBox1.Text == "/")
            {
                textBox1.Clear();
                textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + button10.Text;
            }
            else
                textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + button10.Text;
        }

        private void btnEqual_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double result;
            num2 = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            textBox1.Text = "";
            switch (op)
            {
                case "+":
                    result = num1 + num2;
                    textBox1.Text += result;
                    num1 = result;
                    ch = "+";
                    break;
                case "-":
                    result = num1 - num2;
                    textBox1.Text += result;
                    num1 = result;
                    ch = "-";
                    break;
                case "*":
                    result = num1 * num2;
                    textBox1.Text += result;
                     num1 = result;
                    ch = "*";
                    break;
                case "/":
                    result = num1 / num2;
                    textBox1.Text += result;
                    num1 = result;
                    ch = "/";
                    break;
            }
        }


        private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (ch != "+")
            {
                num1 = double.Parse(textBox1.Text)+ num1;
            }
            else
            {
                num1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
                ch = "";
            }
            textBox1.Text = "";
            op = "+";

        }

        private void btnSub_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ch != "-")
            {
                num1 =  num1 - double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            }
            else
            {
                num1= Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
                ch = "";
            }

            textBox1.Text = "";

            op = "-";

            textBox1.Text += op;

        }

        private void btnMul_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (ch != "*")
            {
            num1 = double.Parse(textBox1.Text) * num1;
            }
            else
            {
                num1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
                ch = "";
            }
            textBox1.Text = "";
            op = "*";

        }

        private void btnDiv_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (ch != "/") 
            {
            num1 = double.Parse(textBox1.Text) / num1;
            }
            else
            {
                num1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
                ch = "";
            }
            textBox1.Text = "";
            op = "/";


        }
```

Comment: ch is string then you might want to use the `.Equal()` method. And you are not setting the textbox text to the your result of substaraction. `textbox1.Text=num1.ToString()`

Comment: I guess it's only showing `-` as an output? It usually goes better when you display the value you want to display. You're resetting it to "" then add `-`..

Comment: its showing wrong output 7-4-3 i gave it shows 8

Comment: try to provide complete (at least for this method) code like what is ch and num1...

Comment: What do you mean you are giving `7-4-3` if that you insert in textbox1 then your code will throw exception at line `double.Parse(textbox1.Text)`

Comment: k i will add my full code

Comment: ohh can you tell the sequence means which method will be called first means equalto or sub?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, since your methods `button1_Click_1` to `button10_Click` all do the same thing, you can replace them with a single method:

```
private void NumberButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var buttonClicked = (Button)sender;
    if (textBox1.Text == "+" || textBox1.Text == "-" || textBox1.Text == "*" || textBox1.Text == "/")
    {
        textBox1.Clear();
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + buttonClicked.Text;
    }
    else
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + buttonClicked.Text;
}
```

Then about your error: In `btnSub_Click` you check for the field `ch`, but you never set it to a value (except for an empty string `ch = ""`) ... maybe you really want to check for `op`? I'm not sure ...

Another thing is with your `btnDiv_Click` method. There you divide the entered value by the value previously entered ... shouldn't it be the other way around?

```
num1 = num1 / double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
```

Best thing would be, you check this things and if it still doesn't work, you set a breakpoint at the beginning of the `btnSub_Click`, check what values your variables have when you click it and debug the method by stepping through it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely in not clearing out the values after pressing "equals". Let's go step by step through your example (7-4-3):

```
1) press 7:
textbox1.Text="7";

2) press -:
num1 =  num1 - double.Parse(textBox1.Text); = 7
ch = "";

3) press 4:
textbox1.Text="4";

4) press -:
num1 =  num1 - double.Parse(textBox1.Text); = 7-4 = 3
ch="";

5) press 3:
textbox1.Text="3";

6) press equals?
num2 = 3;
result = num1 - num2; = 3-3 = 0
textBox1.Text += result; = "0", which is correct
num1 = result; = 0 (accidentaly in this case, but sometimes another value will be left in here)
```

You do not clean up the values after pressing equals, so the subsequent operations will be affected by the previous num1 value. This is not how calculators typically work so I guess this is not your desired behavior and is probably a bug that causes strange results in subsequent operations.

If you're getting correct results on your first operation, but incorrect afterwards, this should be why.